# Comparing php array key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare two array value.  My array1 is like

```
$a1 = array('123' => 'test1', '456' => 'test2', '789' => 'test3');
```

array2 is like

```
$a2 = array('456' => 'match2', '99' => 'match3');

$a3 = array();
```

I want to compare the key value. If `array1` key matches `array2` key, push `array1` element to a new array

I have

```
  for($i=0; $i < count($a1); $i++){
       //i am not sure how to write my codes heree......
        if($a1[$i]==a2[$i]{
            $a3[]=a1$[$i];
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you looked at [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)?

Comment: Beginning to think I should start posting my answers in the comment section instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_intersect_key` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Code:

```
$a1 = array('123' => 'test1', '456' => 'test2', '789' => 'test3');

$a2 = array('456' => 'match2', '99' => 'match3');

$a3 = array_values(array_diff_key($a1, $a2));

print_r($a3);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test3
)
```

This is what you are after right?  It should be faster than a for loop since it's a native PHP function.

Comment: try to elaborate a little bit more the answer, instead of just the link, write some code :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though I haven't tested it

```
foreach ($a1 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (isset($a2[$k1]))
      $a3[$k1] = $v1;
}
```

You loop through all the elments of $a1 and check if that key exists in $a2. If it does you add the element to $a3 (the code above adds it with the existing key, if you want to discard the keys, just use $a3[] = $v1;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1= array('123' => 'test1', '456' => 'test2', '789' => 'test3');
$a2=array('456' => 'match2', '99' => 'match3');
$ai = array_intersect_key($a1, $a2);
$a3 = array_values($ai);
```